# Next js background mp4

Tags: reactjs, видео, background

друзья подскажите плиз, у меня такая ошибка из-за бекграунда в формате mp4... я пытался использовать library но проблема не исчезла... мне в webpack нужно что-то поменять или как, прошу помочь.
"./public/video/ocean.mp4 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an
appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this
file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this binary file)"

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react"
import Layout from "../components/webSite/layout";
import backgroundVideo from "../public/video/ocean.mp4"

const Home = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      videoRef.current.play()
    },5000)
  }, []);

  return <Layout title={"Home"}>
    <video
        ref={videoRef}
        controls
        width="250"
        loop
        muted
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          height: "15rem",
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
        }}>
      <source src={backgroundVideo} type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </Layout>
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Я удалил свой ответ. Поделитесь решением когда, решите проблему.

Comment: а у webpack-a что в конфиге?

Comment: Я не нахожу .тот файл webpack.config.js... и поиск в редакторе не дает результатов,, не подскажете вы именно про какой файл, где он лежит?

Comment: где-то рядом; может он у вас зовется чуть по-другому; в случае create-react-app он где-то в глубине и его рекомендуют не трогать (смотреть только)

Comment: Покажите компоненту Layout, какой там код?